# If $T(\bf{X})$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$, why does the conditional distribution of $\bf{X}$ given $T(\bf{X})$ doesn't depend on $\theta$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, intuition, definition, sufficient-statistics

I know that if $T(\bf{X})$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$, then the conditional distribution of $\bf{X}$ given $T(\bf{X})$ doesn't depend on $\theta$. However, I am not sure why this makes sense.

It seems that we will never know $\theta$, and that $\bf{X}$ to begin with already depends on $\theta$, and that $T(\bf{X})$ is a "coarser" summary than $\bf{X}$, so how can it be that given $T(\bf{X})$, the distribution of $\bf{X}$ no longer depends on $\theta$? Is there an intuition here?

Comment: When I know $T(x)$, I no longer need to know the value of $\theta$ to compute the probability of $X$. It's just sufficient to know the value of $T(x)$

Comment: What is _your_  definition of "sufficient statistic"? One _[standard  definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Mathematical_definition)_  of sufficient statistic is "A statistic $t=T(X)$ is sufficient for underlying parameter $\theta$ precisely if the conditional probability distribution of the data $X$, given the statistic $t=T(X)$, does not depend on the parameter $\theta$." If this is also your definition, then what you are asking is why this definition makes sense.